# Dynamically conversion of image to binary and vice versa

Tags: android, image

How can I convert **image to binary data**..???

I want to send that converted binary data to
another device or to the web server.

Which mechanism is best to do this.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a good example for uploading the image to the server.

- create a bitmap variable before do anything.
- variable to set a name to the image into SD card.
- this variable, you have to put the path for the File, It's up to you.
- sendData is the function name, to call it, you can use something like
  `sendData(null)`.
- remember to wrap it into a try catch.

```
private Bitmap bitmap;
public static String exsistingFileName = "";

public void sendData(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

        // here, change it to your php;
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.myURL.com/myPHP.php");
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(exsistingFileName);

        // you can change the format of you image compressed for what do you want;
        // now it is set up to 640 x 480;
        Bitmap bmpCompressed = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 640, 480, true);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // CompressFormat set up to JPG, you can change to PNG or whatever you want;
        bmpCompressed.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

        // sending a String param;
        entity.addPart("myParam", new StringBody("my value"));

        // sending a Image;
        // note here, that you can send more than one image, just add another param, same rule to the String;
        entity.addPart("myImage", new ByteArrayBody(data, "temp.jpg"));
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(   response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String sResponse = reader.readLine();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("myApp", "Some error came up");
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i display the image in imageview from binary string

Comment: @RajeshRajaram 

mImageViewArrowName.setImageBitmap(new BitmapFactory().decodeByteArray(mByte, 0, mByte.length));

Comment: @SilentKiller does you code above can be implemented to store in oracle database? And how I send the byte array to the server, should be in POST method?

Answer (score 9):

Image is in Bitmap then use the following code to convert that image to binary. By using following code

```
Bitmap photo;// this is your image.
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

To get Image From Binary use the following sample:

```
Bitmap bMap = null;

bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
Let `img` contains Bitmap image

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(img, "png", baos);
baos.flush();
byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
```

`imageInByte` now contains bytedata of bitmap image.

For converting reverse

```
Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgArray, 0,imgArray.length);
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: should i convert the image from jpeg to bitmap.?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to send to webserver use `HttpPost` request using `HttpClient`